# How to get a relative path of a resource file in a Maven project?

Tags: java, maven

My project uses Maven and is a little bit complicated. I can't seem to get a relative path for a resource file.
The structure is like this:

```
project_folder
    |-package1
       |-src
          |-test
              |-java
                |-folder1
                  |-folder2
                     ...
                       |-foldern
                           |-**myfile**

              |-resources
                |-folder
                  |-**targetfile**
```

In `test`, there is a `java` folder and a `resources folder`. **`myfile`** is deep within the `java` folder. So in **`myfile`**, I want to refer to the relative path of **`target file`**. What is the path?

Comment: Where is the pom located and is there any configuration to change the default test source and test resources directories?

Comment: Refer from where?  From a Java class, e.g. classloader?  From a shell script? From Maven Pom.xml?

Comment: there is a pom file under the project folder and a pom file under every package

Comment: I referred to it in a put function, so I need a string for that. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have not changed the defaults for test source and resource location:

```
MyFile.class.getResourceAsStream("../../../folder/targetfile");
```

with N `"../"` instead of 3. It would of course be easier to do:

```
MyFile.class.getResourceAsStream("/folder/targetfile");
```

Comment: I use the relative path in a put method, so I can only pass a **string** in this function, so is there any string form for this relative path? Thanks

Comment: `"../../../folder/targetfile"` with N `"../"` may work, how is the value you are passing to `put()` being used though? Also why does the path have to be relative?

Comment: because i am doing some dev in my local machine but i will upload it to our server, so i need a  relative path. Because myfile has so many folders above so there may be 8 ../ so i am wondering is there any shorter expressions. Thanks!

Comment: `MyFile.class.getResource("/folder/targetfile").toString()` should return the correct path to the file on both your dev machine and on the server (assuming you are running from source on both machines). If you are running from a jar you should use `getResourceAsStream()` to create an `InputStream` to read the file.